# Center a absolute positioned div vertical?

Tags: css

I have this:

```css
.ce_text.forward {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
color: #2d353c;
}
.ce_text.forward p {
position: relative;
}
.ce_text.forward .fill_bottom {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
bottom: 0;
left: -865px;
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
background-color: #ecedee;
top: 0px;
right: 0;
transition: left 0.3s linear 0s;
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.ce_text.forward:hover .fill_bottom {
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ce_text forward block"><div class="fill_bottom"></div>

  
      <p><a href="" target="_blank"><strong>Headline</strong>Test Test test test<span>Lesen Sie mehr</span></a></p>  
  
  
</div>
```

It works in chrome but not in firefox, can some one help me with the css?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfwvhnh2/)

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly is not working.

Comment: In chrome the div fill_bottom is vertical centered, in firefox its more on the bottom.

Comment: Would like to know more.. What issue you are facing.. As I have tested it in firefox, I am not able to see any issue. What exactly you are willing to do

Comment: There is a hover effect, that the div fill_bottom goes from left to right and the div fill_bottom is positioned perfect in chrome, in firefox the div is not centerd at the hover effect.

Comment: It's related to `margin: auto;` on `.ce_text.forward .fill_bottom`. Firefox is not rendering it the same as Chrome. remove it and you can re-create the problem in Chrome.

Comment: But this one is working in firefox:
http://codepen.io/davidhc/pen/HBzkL

Comment: Ok, its working because the centered div is smaller than the parent div but in my case, the centered div is bigger than the parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in Firefox seems to be caused by the usage of `margin: auto`. I have completely re-built your example to eliminate this.

## New and Improved

- **No fixed height**. Height is controlled by a percentage (which can be modified) and a min-height.
- **No extra markup**. The triangle is created with a pseudo element and rotated. The text is centered with its `<a>` wrapper.
- **Centered triangle**. The triangle is centered at any height with `bottom: 50%` and a negative bottom margin of half its height.
- **No gaps** - The triangle is large enough to eliminate any spacing in the corners. If you need it to be even larger, it can be as large as required; just keep the height to width ratio 1:1 and increase the size of the negative bottom margin.

  ```css
  * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  html, body {
      height: 100%;
  }
  h1 {
      background: #333;
      height: 40%;
      min-height: 140px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 0;
  }
  h1 a {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -0.56em;
      left: 100px;
  }
  h1:before {
      content:'';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50%;
      margin-bottom: -1000px;
      left: -2000px;
      height: 2000px;
      width: 2000px;
      background: #F00;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      transition: left 0.3s;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  h1:hover:before {
      left: 0;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <h1><a>Text</a></h1>
  ```

---

## Old Solution

**Archived** - fixed height option (no transform, should work back to IE8)

I have approached this differently:

- The right triangle and the bar are made with pseudo elements and are positioned with percentages
- `z-index: -1` keeps the pseudo elements behind the text.
- `overflow: hidden` prevents the scroll bar when the triangle is pushed outside.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.headline {
 height: 100px;
 background: #333;
 color: #FFF;
 position: relative; 
 z-index: 2;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
 padding: 30px 0 70px 50px;
        overflow: hidden;
}
.headline:before {
 width: 30%;
 content:'';
 display: block;
 height: 100px;
 background: #F00;
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 z-index: -1;
}
.headline:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;
 border-top: solid 50px transparent;
 border-left: solid 50px #F00;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 left: 30%;
 position: absolute;
 top:0; 
 transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 z-index: -1;
}
.headline:hover:before {
 width: 100%;
}
.headline:hover:after {
 left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="headline">Text</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is, that I dont have a fixed height, so the height needs to be flexible.

Comment: What is the min-height and max-height that you need it to be?

Comment: The min-height would be about 140px and max-height 300px

Comment: @LydiaMaier - Please test out my New and Improved solution :)

Comment: Danke you, thats awsome

Comment: @LydiaMaier - No worries! This question stopped me from sleeping last night because I knew there was such a simple solution - enjoy!